# Does JRuby not have MemoryImageSource in awt.Image?

Tags: java, jruby, memoryimagesource

Using: jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.7.0_76-b13 +indy [linux-i386]

When I try to use memory image source, which is in java.awt.Image, I get an "uninitialized constant" error. If I explicitly do

```
import java.awt.Image.MemoryImageSource
```

Then I get "undefined method `MemoryImageSource' for Java::JavaAwt::Image:Class
".  Does JRuby just not support this class for some reason?  Or, is MemoryImageSource somehow not in 1.7?

Edit: I wrote a quick Java test:

```
import java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource;
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MemoryImageSource ms;
        System.out.println("Hello World! I can find MemoryImageSource"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

And I get no problems finding MemoryImageSource, so it seems like the problem is JRuby.

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_76"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
```

Edit:

Realized it's not clear that other Java aspects work fine in JRuby (I can create a JFrame and draw little squares on it with a JPanel, for example).

Edit:

Maybe the problem is with how I'm trying to import MemoryImageSource? When I write a Java class that uses MemoryImageSource, I can access it from JRuby just fine (just not MemoryImageSource directly).  For now, it's a decent workaround because my java returns the Image I created from MemoryImageSource without Ruby complaining.

I am still curious how I went wrong, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just did something completely different (watch for proper casing) :

`java_import java.awt.Image.MemoryImageSource` first resolves
`java.awt.Image` which in your case (unfortunately) exists and than tries to call the `MemoryImageSource` method on the Java class

what you're after is `java_import java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource` thus JRuby assumes `java.awt.image` is a package and looks for a class under it

Comment: Ah! I was under the mistaken assumption that you had to capitalize Java classes to access them from Ruby (since that is a Ruby convention).  I think it was because I'd seen other references to java.awt.Image and extrapolated. Thank you!